# Why is the distributor ID of the latest RPi OS Lite image 'Debian' and not 'Raspbian'?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I just flashed the latest RPi OS Lite image (64 bit) Bullseye and loaded onto a RPi 4B (4GB) using the RPI imager. Released 2022-04-04

When I booted the Pi, I checked its `lsb_release -a` and I realised, the distributor ID has been changed. Since my Ansible playbook checks LSB release ID, it's currently erroring out.

While I can change my code, I wonder why the distributor ID is not Raspbian anymore.

Comment: If you don't want Debian DON'T use 64 bit (there is little point  in 64 bit anyway).

Comment: @Milliways Thanks for the suggestion, I think it clarifies quite a bit. 
So it looks to me the source code behind are all the same behind the scene and I understand that there is a difference between 32 bit and 64 bit version of the RPi images. 
But I don't know why is there such a difference? because it can cause some confusion...